# Add custom header to Xcode project to hold related imports in one place

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header

I've realised that that I have like 4 or 5 related .h files that I have to import at few places. It seems reasonable to create a one .h file, add all imports to it and then only import one new file instead of 5.
First of all, is this a common practice? Or is there a nicer way?

In Xcode, when I try to do so using File -> New -> File... -> Source -> Header File the newly created header holds this:

```
#ifndef MyProject_MyProjetCommonHeader_h
#define MyProject_MyProjetCommonHeader_h

#endif
```

Not sure why these preprocessor commands needed. And it doesn't recognise (autocomplete) any headers when I try to use #import. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could import all the header files into `MyProjectCommonHeader.h` file.

```
#import "Header1.h"
#import "Header2.h"
```

And then to use `Header1.h` and `Header2.h` in another file just import `MyProjectCommonHeader.h` in the desired files.

The `#ifndef` commands are explained nicely here http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/ifndef.html

Comment: Any idea why autocomplete not picking up header names in this file?

Comment: It could be Xcode was indexing, which sometimes causes autocomplete temporarily to be turned off.

Comment: nah, it doesn't recognise any headers specifically in this file. But the whole idea does work nicely if I copy and paste imports.